# what if _POSIX_VDISABLE value is -1?

Tags: posix

In POSIX _POSIX_VDISABLE value if -1, there is no disabling character for special character for all the terminal device files; otherwise the value is the disabling character value..

Can please anyone help me understand this. I m not able to get the exact meaning of this.

Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [definition of special characters](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_239.html), that should mean (thre '-1' value), that all those special characters are active:

> In canonical input, the terminal driver recognizes a number of special characters which perform various control functions.
>   These include the `ERASE` character (usually <kbd>DEL</kbd>) for editing input, and other editing characters.
>   The INTR character (normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>) for sending a `SIGINT` signal, and other signal-raising characters, may be available in either canonical or noncanonical input mode.

And you have a lot of those specal characters:

- [Characters for Input Editing](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_240.html#SEC240)
- [BSD Extensions to Editing Characters](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_241.html#SEC241)
- [Characters that Cause Signals](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_242.html#SEC242)
- [Special Characters for Flow Control](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_243.html#SEC243)
- [Other Special Characters](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_244.html#SEC244)

---

The question has been raised to see if [such a value was portable](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG15/docs/rr/9945-1/9945-1-27.html) (did always compiled) in 1997:

> The wording in section 2.9.4:
>
> If any of the constants in Table 2-11 are defined to have value -1 in the header ....
>
> can suggest, on casual reading, code like the following to minimize size
>   and optimize efficiency for each implementation:

```
#ifdef _POSIX_VDISABLE
#if    _POSIX_VDISABLE == -1
    /* code that assumes no vdisable capability */
#else
    /* code that assumes vdisable capability */
#endif
#else
    /* code that uses pathconf() to determine vdisable capability */
#endif
```

The [interpretation #34](http://standards.ieee.org/reading/ieee/interp/1003-1-90_int/pasc-1003.1-34.html) suggests that it will.

> By using these values at COMPILE-TIME, a portable POSIX.1 application can avoid loading all pathconf() related code associated with a symbol in Table 2-11 when the symbol is defined.

Comment: The strange thing is that glibc seems to treat it as an unsigned char, which I have never figured out.

Comment: @Tim: Hence my links to the interpretations: "The standard makes no requirement that the constant _POSIX_VDISABLE be a preprocessor number."

Comment: Thank you so much.. By the way i m still a student pursuing my Computer Science Engineering :), How do guys have so much of knowledge(asking with respect). I mean i feel, I hardly know anything in this world :(

Comment: @Nagaraj: Err... in this exact instance, Google help me for the link to the interpretations of `_POSIX_VDISABLE` in compile time ;)

Answer (score 4):

My terminal has special keys, like ^C to interrupt, ^\ to dump core, ^W to erase a word, and ^U to erase a line. Special keys exist in xterm and other terminal emulators, but they are not the same in every terminal. POSIX apps can call tcgetattr() or tcsetattr() in <termios.h> to get or set these special keys. They can also disable some keys, for example:

```
tcgetattr(fd, tp);
tp->c_lflag &= ~ISIG;                /* disable all the signal keys */
tp->c_cc[WERASE] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;  /* disable the word-erase key */
tcsetattr(fd, tp);
```

Before POSIX.1-2001, support for _POSIX_VDISABLE was optional. There were 3 possibilities:

- _POSIX_VDISABLE was defined and not -1. Then any terminal can use _POSIX_VDISABLE to disable a special key.
- _POSIX_VDISABLE was defined and -1. Then no terminal can use _POSIX_VDISABLE.
- _POSIX_VDISABLE was not defined. Then the value to disable a special key might be different for each terminal. A call like `pathconf("/dev/tty", _PC_VDISABLE)` would return the value for that terminal, or -1 if that terminal doesn't have a value to disable a special key.

When systems added <termios.h>, all or almost all systems made _POSIX_VDISABLE defined and not -1.  I looked at some old systems in [the Unix tree](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl). All of Minix 1.5 (1989), Linux 0.96c (1992), and 4.4BSD (1993) have _POSIX_VDISABLE defined and not -1. (Before POSIX, <termios.h> did not exist, and systems used another header like <sgtty.h> to configure the terminal.)

POSIX-1.2001 simply required that _POSIX_VDISABLE is defined and not -1. [POSIX.1-2001 said for <unistd.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/unistd.h.html#tag_13_80),

> _POSIX_VDISABLE
>
> > This symbol shall be defined to be the value of a character that shall disable terminal special character handling as described in [<termios.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/termios.h.html). This symbol shall always be set to a value other than -1.

[The rationale says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/xrat/xbd_chap02.html#tag_01_02),

> As part of the revision some alignment has occurred of the options with the FIPS 151-2 profile on the POSIX.1-1990 standard. The following options from the POSIX.1-1990 standard are now mandatory:
>
> - _POSIX_JOB_CONTROL
> - _POSIX_SAVED_IDS
> - _POSIX_VDISABLE

Comment: Great… except neither the Linux uapi kernel headers nor Linux klibc define `_POSIX_VDISABLE` so we still have to `#ifndef` though I’m doing a leap right now and assume that, if it is indeed defined, it’s not `-1`. Adding insult to injury, glibc on kFreeBSD defines it to `((unsigned char)'\377')` which cannot be used in a `#if`… :'(