# What does M-^? in stty output mean?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, stty

I'm trying to troubleshoot some terminal issues I'm having connecting from my Windows laptop to a linux server using the Git Bash shell.  The screen does not appear to be refreshing properly (clear does not clear the screen, after exiting vim and man output stays on the screen, etc).  I'm looking at the stty settings and comparing it with another linux server where I don't have these issues.  One of things I see on my working server is `eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;`.  Can someone explain the notation to me?  How can I replicate this setting on the other server?

Comment: wild guess... end of line produces a  control M??!!

Comment: Wouldn't that show as `^M` then?  For example `intr = ^C;`

Answer (score 2):

[`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) is limited to single-byte characters.

`bash` uses the naming convention (as do a few other programs) of an `M-` prefix to denote the meta flag.  Conventionally, `^?` is ASCII DEL (127 decimal, 0x7f hex), so I would expect `M-^?` to be 255 (0xff).

Depending on the implementation (see discussion of `_POSIX_VDISABLE`)  `stty` might show that value as `undef`:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Regarding *meta*, ncurses has some documentation in [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous):

> If the terminal has a "meta key" which  acts  as  a  shift
>   key,  setting  the  *8th*  bit of any character transmitted,
>   this fact can be indicated with km.   Otherwise,  software
>   will assume that the *8th* bit is parity and it will usually
>   be cleared.  If strings exist to turn this "meta mode"  on
>   and off, they can be given as **`smm`** and **`rmm`**.

and with the [`keyname`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name) function, it returns values in that form:

> Values above 128 are either meta  characters  (if  the
>   screen  has  not been initialized, or if [meta](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-meta) has been
>   called with a TRUE parameter), shown in the ***M-X***  notation,  or  are displayed as themselves.  In the latter
>   case, the values may not be  printable;  this  follows
>   the X/Open specification.

Further reading:

- [Alt-keys do not work in bash](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode)
- [9.13 Why doesn’t my Meta key work in an xterm window?](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Meta-key-does-not-work-in-xterm.html) (GNU Emacs FAQ)
- [what if _POSIX_VDISABLE value is -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891425/what-if-posix-vdisable-value-is-1)
- [17.4.9 Special Characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Special-Characters.html) (The GNU C Library)